# Azure ApiApp - listen for ServiceBus msg

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azureservicebus, azure-functions, azure-api-apps

Say a have a `CreateOrder` method inside a ApiApp project.

Now I need to also trigger the `CreateOrder` when I receive a `CreateOrderMessage` from a ServiceBus queue.

I understand that this could be easily done using Azure Functions with a queue trigger. But that adds more complexity (introduces another concepts, will require a new repository, docs etc) So my question is simply:

Could I listen for queue messages inside of a WebApi project? (I know spinning up a new thread involves some problems)

Thanks for any suggestions

Larsi

Comment: you can have a look at hangfire. It is designed to run background tasks inside asp.net app. http://hangfire.io/. I think they support Azure Servicebus.

Comment: Why not just make a Function that calls your WebApi? use the same function for all calls, it will just be a gateway persay, all your logic sticks to your WebAPIs/microservices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, yes, you can. As you already mentioned, this is not a recommended approach, mainly due to possible complications in manual thread management, life cycle of your WebApi app, etc. Ideally message processing should be done in a web job, worker role, function, service, etc.

Answer (score 1):

We also could easily do that with azure function, we can import WebJob SDK to azure function using 
 `#r  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs`, more detail info please refer [azure functions C# developer reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies). We can get the more info from reference [how to create azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function).

We also can do that via WebJob,  we also can easily [deploy WebJob with VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs). 
The following is the demo code：

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("inputqueue")] string message, 
        TextWriter logger)

    {

         // Todo

    }
```

More details please refer to [How to use Azure Service Bus with the WebJobs SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-service-bus#a-idtriggera-how-to-trigger-a-function-when-a-service-bus-queue-message-is-received).